# uniform density probability

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

If $a$ is uniformly distributed over [-22,31], what is the probability that the roots of the equation are both real:

$$x^2+ax+a+63=0$$

I have solved this in another situation. I know that I need the expression under the square root to be positive. So,

$$0 \le b^2-4ac$$

which in my case is

$$0 \le a^2-4a-252$$

but from here I am having a hard time finding out what I should be doing. I tried graphing it but I am not sure that I was doing it properly.

Comment: I did this for $x^2+Bx+C$ and came to $C \le \frac{B^2}{4}$. So then I know to integrate $\frac{B^2}{4}$ over my region. I am having a hard time figuring out what to do with the above expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

You just need to figure out what values of $a$ obey $a^2-4a-252>0$ and then determine what fraction of the range $(-22,31)$  that is.

Comment: Yes Thank you very much. I actually solved it. I was not realizing that $a^2-4a-252 = (a+14)(a-18)$